# How does memmove on array of pointers in C/C++ work?

Tags: c, memmove

I have an array of array like this :

```
double **Arr = malloc(N*sizeof(double*));
for(int j = 0; j < N-1; j++)
  Arr[j] = malloc(M*sizeof(double))
```

Theses arrays are full of values. And I want to shift some arrays (the N-i last ones). Are there any differences between these 2 lines ?

```
for(int j = i; j < N-1; j++)
  for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
    Arr[j][k] = Arr[j+1][k];
```

or

```
memmove(&(Arr[i]), &(Arr[i+1]), (N-1-i)*sizeof(double*));
```

Comment: You don't have an array of arrays, you have an array of pointers. Think about the difference copying the elements of an array and copying a pointer.

Comment: memmove is basically memcpy but it's allows overlap between `src` and `dest` pointers (meaning it will also be slower).

Comment: @molbdnilo he doesn't have an array of pointers, he has a pointer to pointers.

Comment: Consider using `double (*arr)[M] = malloc( sizeof(double[N][M]) );` and then `memcpy(arr[i], arr[i+1], sizeof(double[M]));`. It will be far more cache-friendly and easier to read too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick anwsers.

Indeed, I have a pointer to pointers !
@Lundin I cannot defined my array like `double (*arr)[M]` because M is a variable.

If I understand well your answers, I can only remove one for loop using:
`for(int j=i; j<N-1; j++) memcpy(&(Arr[k][0]), &(Arr[k+1][0]), M*sizeof(double));`

Comment: @FlorianAubin Update your C compiler to a standard one made this millennium and you can.

Comment: `Theses arrays are full of values` Not so full, `Arr[N-1]` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any differences between these 2 lines ?

Yes, they are very different. And the second is leaking memory.

Explanation:

After initialization like:

```
double **Arr = malloc(N*sizeof(double*));
for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
  Arr[j] = malloc(M*sizeof(double))
```

(note: I changed the N-1 to N as I assumed it to be a mistake)

The allocated memory now looks like:

[image]

When you then do:

```
for(int j = i; j < N; j++)
  for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
    Arr[j][k] = Arr[j+1][k];
```

You copy the doubles from a horizontal array to the horizontal array above. Like:

[image]

When you do:

```
memmove(&(Arr[i]), &(Arr[i+1]), (N-1-i)*sizeof(double*));
```

You copy the double-pointers in the vertical array one position up. Like:

[image]

So it's very different operations that the 2 code blocks do.

And the `memmove` is bad as it leaks memory.

Answer (score 0):

The first copies `M` numbers `N-1-i` times, and the second copies `N-1-i` pointers once.
That is, if `double` and `double*` are the same size, the first copies `M` times as much memory as the second.
(And is less cache-friendly.)

Simplifying to just two pointers:

```
 double *arr = malloc(M * sizeof(double));
 double *arr2 = malloc(M * sizeof(double));
```

the difference is the same as between

```
 for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) arr2[k] = arr[k];
```

and

```
arr2 = arr;
```

Which one you should use depends on what you're after; copying the pointers or copying the elements.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any differences between these 2 lines ?

Let's take:

```
memmove(&(Arr[i]), &(Arr[i+1]), (N-1-i)*sizeof(double*));
```

Basically what it does can be represented by copying byte-by-byte the specified amount of bytes from one pointer to another. So it can be written in this I hope correct code:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < (N-1-i)*sizeof(double*); ++j) {
    *( ((char*)&Arr[i]) + j ) = *( ((char *)(&Arr[i + 1]) + j );
```

Puff, it makes a big technical difference, but let's remove `sizeof(double*)` and the casts:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < N - 1 - i; ++j)
    *(&Arr[i] + j) = *(&Arr[i + 1] + j);
```

The `&Arr[i]` is equal to `&*(Arr + i)` which is equal to `Arr + i`, so:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < N - 1 - i; ++j) {
    *(Arr + i + j) = *(Arr + i + j + 1);
```

The `*(a + i)` is equal to `a[i]`, so we can:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < N - 1 - i; ++j) {
    Arr[i + j] = Arr[i + j + 1];
```

As `i + j` is on both sides and `j` starts from `0`, we could just start from `i`:

```
for (size_t j = i; j < N - 1; ++j) {
    Arr[j] = Arr[j + 1];
```

Now this copies the pointers values(!) from `Arr[j + 1]` into `Arr[j]`. This does something very different then copying the values that are pointed to by the pointers:

```
for(int j = i; j < N - 1; j++)
    for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)
         Arr[j][k] = Arr[j + 1][k];
```

On the other hand, the above code could be translated to:

```
for(int j = i; j < N - 1; j++)
    memcpy(Arr[j], Arr[j + 1], M * sizeof(double));
  //^^^^^^ or memove, but I guess not
```

> Theses arrays are full of values

Your initialization routine that you have showed has this loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < N-1; j++)
   Arr[j] = malloc(M*sizeof(double))
```

Being sane and assuming `N > 1`, then `Arr[N - 1]` is left uninitialized. So, accessing in the above loops `Arr[j + 1]` for the last loop when `j = N - 2` is accessing uninitialized value. And the loop `for(int k = 0; k < M; k++)` `Arr[j][k] = Arr[j + 1][k];` dereferences uninitialized pointer in `Arr[j + 1][k]` and is undefined behavior.